# How can I make the HTML5 iframe seamless attribute work within my Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html

I've setup my Rails 3 app with only

```
<%= yield %>
```

in the application.html.erb and pages.html.erb layout files (Pages is my controller), and I have a view with only the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<title>My Title</title>
<body>
<iframe src="http://myiframesource.com" seamless="seamless" width="100%" height="1949px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

But the iframe still has a border around it and does not completely fill the page when I look at it in my browser (I tried several).  According to W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_seamless.asp
the seamless attribute should have no borders nor scrollbars and " should look like it is part of the parent document."

I'd also like to not have to tell the iframe what width/height to be, and just have it take up as much space as it needs.

Why does the seamless attribute seem to not be working right?

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because your browser doesn't support seamless iframes.  As far as I know it doesn't work in either Firefox 4 or Google Chromium 11, you'll have to wait until someone actually implements it.  As for the iframe taking as much space as it needs I don't think that there is currently a way to do this without JavaScript.  For a JavaScript solution just search the web, there are several tutorials about this.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that explains it.  I hadn't checked whether the browsers had implemented it - I was blindly assuming they were doing HTML5 just because of the DOCTYPE.
And JS should work for the auto-sizing, if I want to go that route (I do in fact know what size the iframe _should_ be so I can hard-code it for now)